# How to get a string from an element in an arrayList of strings using an Adapter for a recyclerview

Tags: android, adapter, android-adapter, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I've created a RecyclerView that gets inflated with an ArrayList of Strings and I want to put extra information in an intent for the next activity to get the information. I can pass the position of the element in the reclyclerview(within the intent), but I also want to send the string value that appears in that element. The layout used by the adapter for the recylcerView has nothing but a TextView for displaying the values in the ArrayList of strings.

The problem is in the Adapter, because I want to be able to put an String as extra information in the intent. And what I have to change is the onItemClick method parameters inside ItemClickListener, but I don't know what to do next.

Here's the Adapter:

**Adapter_dishes_rv.java**

```
public class Adapter_dishes_rv extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_dishes_rv.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    Adapter_dishes_rv(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_simple_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameoftypeofdish);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

I think that all I have to change is just the OnItemClick parameters but then what else?

Here's the layout just in case:

**recyclerview_simple_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameoftypeofdish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then there's the main Activity:

**FoodFamilyActivity.java**

```
public class FoodFamilyActivity extends Activity implements Adapter_dishes_rv.ItemClickListener {

    Adapter_dishes_rv adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_family);

        ArrayList<String> dishesOfAFamily = new String[]{"Sopa de pobre", "Sopa de pescado", "Sopa de sobre"}
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.FamilyDishes);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new Adapter_dishes_rv(this, dishesOfAFamily);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FoodFamilyActivity.this, DishActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(DishActivity.EXTRA_DISHNO, (int) position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

If you need anything else tell me, because I really need help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following function to your adapter

```
public String getDishForPosition(int position) {
        if (mData != null && mData.size() > 0) {
            return mData.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You are already getting the concerned position using `getAdapterPosition()`. Using the above function you can get the string from the list .

Change your interface to

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position,String dishes);
    }
```

Now you have the required string in your activity where you can pass it to Intent

Comment: Happy to help :)